# Proving that $\tau=\bigcap \limits_{i\in I} \tau_i$ is a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

In my general topology textbook one exercise ask me to prove the following:

> - If $\tau_1,\tau_2,...,\tau_n$ are topologies on a set $X$, then $\tau = \bigcap \limits_{i=1}^n \tau_i$ is a topology on $X$.
> - If for each $i \in I$, for some index set $I$, each $\tau_i$ is a topology on the set $X$, then $\tau=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} \tau_i$ is a topology on $X$.

In the first one I proved using mathematical induction that $\tau = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n \tau_i$ is a topology on $X$. Doesn't that proof aplly also to the second statement? What is the difference between statement one and two?

Comment: No, it doesn't imply the second part. By induction you prove a statement is true for $n$ topologies for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But there is no step in which you proved that it is true for infinitely many topologies as well. This is a common mistake about induction.

Comment: So induction can't prove something for infinite many things? Only for a finite number of things?

Comment: The number of topologies we intersect does not matter. Induction is not needed at all. See the proof by @VictorHugo .

Comment: Yes But I want to know if induction works for infinite cases and if not, why.

Comment: Yes, induction only proves for a finite number of topologies. Note that in every step of the induction process you prove it for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but there is no step in which you proved it is true for infinitely many topologies.

Comment: Is there any thing we can do to generalize that to an infinite number of topologies? Like a limit or something like that?

Comment: Because if induction works for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we should be able to make $n \to \infty$ right? @Mark

Comment: No, in general we can't. There is a difference between a statement being true for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the statement being true for infinitely many objects. I'll give an example. In any topological space it is true that the union of of $n$ closed sets is closed, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But the union of infinitely many closed sets might not be closed. For example, take $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology. Then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},1]=(0,1]$, the union is not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in every topology so they are in $\tau$.

ii) Let $U=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, with $A_j \in \tau$. Then, $U$ is open in every topology, since $A_i$ is in $\tau$ for all $i\in I$. Therefore, $U \in \tau$.

iii) Let $V=A_1\cap\dots\cap A_n$ be a finite intersection of elements of the intersection.  Then, $V$ is open in every topology, since $A_i$ is in $\tau$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$. Thus, $V  \in \tau$.