# Intersection of topologies: two topologies, finite number of topologies and topologies indexed by index set - why we need distinct proofs

Tags: general-topology

I'm self learning topology by reading "Topology without tears" by Sidney A. Morris. There are three exercises related to intersection of topologies:

1. Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be topologies on $X$. Prove that $\tau_1 \cap \tau_2$ is a topology on X
2. If $\tau_1, \tau_1, ..., \tau_n$ are topologies on $X$, prove $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \tau_{i}$ is a topology on X
3. If for each $i \in I$, for some index set $I$, each $\tau_i$ is a topology on the set $X$, prove $\bigcap_{i \in I} \tau_{i}$ is a topology on X

Why do we need three distinct proofs for 2 topologies, countable number of topologies and (possibly infinite number of?) topologies indexed by index set? Why we cannot naturally extend the proof from 1. to 2. and 3? Is there other similar construct in mathematics that is true for two operands but not when taking account more ?

Comment: Well, 3. implies 2. implies 1., so if you prove 3., you don't need to prove the others separately.

Comment: An example comes from topology itself. We only require the intersection of two (and hence finitely many by induction) open sets to be open. You can easily construct examples (say in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$) where the intersection of infinitely many open sets is not open.

Comment: @Thorgott yes of course, what I was aiming at I guess is... it's simpler (slash shorter) to prove 1. so while we can prove 3. and cover all cases, I wonder why not prove 1. and assume it holds for more topologies (even infinitely many). And then I wondered whether we can make such assumption, hence my kind request for example where such property may hold for finite number of operands but not for infinite. I have found an example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738179/proving-that-tau-bigcap-limits-i-in-i-tau-i-is-a-topology-on-x?rq=1 which proves we cant always make this assump

Comment: @TippingOctopus thanks to you, I have found the example above. Thanks! (The example is in the comment)

Comment: Exercises are sometimes (often? usually?) written not with mathematical efficiency in mind, but instead with teaching in mind. In this case: try the easy case first; then try this more general case; and finally try the most general case. And, of course, if you immediately perceive the steps of generalization and go straight to a proof of the more general case, then even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is clearly no actual requirement for three separate theorems, since the last implies the others and is easily proved without appealing to either of the others. The reason for having all three exercises is probably pædagogical: even though the arguments for (1) and (3) are essentially the same, many students find it easier to think about two topologies than to think about an arbitrary family of topologies. As for (2), it can of course be proved by the same argument, but it can also be proved by induction on $n$, using (1) to carry out the induction step, much as one proves that the intersection of any finite family of open sets is open.